# PDO insert array in array

Tags: php, pdo, prepared-statement

i'm confused ... I am encountering a tiny issue that drives me crazy.
I have arrays in an array which i'd like to insert into an SQL table.
My issue is that i don't figure out how to insert arrays in an array ...

**The arrays:**
Array ( [1] => Array ( [diploma] => Master [institut] => IAE ) [2] => Array ( [diploma] => Licence [institut] => Université ) )

Any piece of advice is welcome :) Thanks a lot from France !

```
<input id="mytext-{cid}" type="text" name="training[{cid}][diploma]" placeholder="Diplôme" value="">
<input name="training[{cid}][institut]" placeholder="Institut">

 try
{
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host='.$host.';dbname='.$bd, $login, $password);
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
}
catch (Exception $e) //Le catch est chargé d’intercepter une éventuelle erreur
{
die ($e->getMessage());
}
global $pdo;

// INSERT MySQL

if (empty($_POST['training'])){

}
else {      
    $sql = "INSERT INTO user_resume (Diplome,Institut) VALUES (?,?)";
    $stmt= $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute($_POST['training']);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to loop over your multidimensional array and use named placeholders so the values match up.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO user_resume (Diplome, Institut) VALUES (:diploma, :institut)";
$stmt= $pdo->prepare($sql);
foreach($_POST['training'] as $params){
    $stmt->execute($params);
}
```